# Jython Decorators: 1st arg can't be coerced to org.python.core.PyFunction

Tags: java, python, decorator, jython

I'm building a way to script CraftBukkit (Minecraft modded server software) with Python.

I do this by loading a Python script with Jython, and then having decorators for events, etc.

I'm currently implementing the event decorators, but I have a problem: Decorators with no arguments work fine, but as soon as I add an argument, it starts complaining about there not being enough arguments.

This works:

```
@script.event
def test(event):
    print "hi" # Works

public void event(PyFunction func) {
    return func;
}
```

This does not:

```
@script.event("player.PlayerMoveEvent", "normal")
def test(event):
    print "player moved!" # TypeError: event(): 1st arg can't be coerced to org.python.core.PyFunction

public void event(PyFunction func, PyString eventType, PyString priority) {
    // Do all kinds of crap
    return func;
}
```

Here's my Java code:
http://pastebin.com/GsULYdJr

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Jython. The equivalent pure Python code shows the actual problem (I'm leaving out the class or namespace `script` for simplicity):

```
def event(func, event_type, priority):
    # ...
    return func

@event("player.PlayerMoveEvent", "normal")
def test(event):
    print "player moved"
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: priority
```

and it's caused by a misunderstanding of decorators. You expect the decorated function definition to be executed like this

```
def test(event):
    print "player moved"

test = event(test, "player.PlayerMoveEvent", "normal")
```

but it's executed like this:

```
__decorator = event("player.PlayerMoveEvent", "normal")

def test(event):
    print "player moved"

test = __decorator(test)
```

The part behind the `@` is evaluated in isolation, and the result of *that* is called with the `test` function as argument. The normal fix in Python is to use a closure, but that's probably cumbersome in Java. It's probably easiest to write part of the decorator in Python and leave the Java code as it currently is:

```
def script(event_type, priority):
    def decorate(func):
        return script.event(func, event_type, priority)
    return decorate
```

Comment: I am not a smart man. This makes no sense to me :)
Mind explaining it in layman's terms? I can't actually add Python code, it has to be Java.

Comment: @CrateMuncher Which parts specifically?

Comment: pretty much the whole thing. I don't see the difference between your first example and your second.

Comment: @CrateMuncher I assume by first and second example you mean the "executed like this ..." parts? I'll condense it: `script.event(test, event_type, priority)` versus `script.event(event_type, priority)(test)`. Even if higher order functions are glibberish to you, don't you at least see that the order of the arguments is wrong in the second?

Comment: I don't know enough Java or Jython to give you code for that. Basically you need the moral equivalent of my last Python snippet, but lacking closures, you'll need to create a Python-callable object (however one does that from Java) for `script` to return.